# Sharing a model between multiple views in backbone

Tags: architecture, backbone.js

I have a model and view for user created appointments. I am adding the ability for staff to create 'official' appointments. These appointments will have additional options and events available, but for the most part the appointment models will have similar attributes (a date, a location, a client).

What I would like to do is have a single model that takes care of all appointments and pass in parameters to create default attributes depending on if a user or a staff member created the appointment.

Is this a clean way organize appointments, or should I be having separate models for each type of appointment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a place where you'd want to extend your existing `Appointment` model.  Don't just set different attributes based on who creates it.

```
var Appointment= Appointment.Model.extend({
     ...
});

var UserAppointment = Appointment.extend({
     ...
});

var StaffAppointment = Appointment.extend({
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always found that creating a class diagram really helps identify what I'd have to do with respect to my objects. In your case, what I envision is a main Appointment class with subclasses for the various types of appointments. Here's a simple UML class diagram representation:

[image: Class diagram of appointment]

This might seem trivial, but going through this will help you identify commonalities between your classes that can be placed in the parent class, and will help you avoid writing a bunch of code in your subclasses in case you missed something. If you're interested, look up Astah Community edition. It's free and very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with multiple Appointment Models is that part from being clean from an Object Orientation perspective, it's not quite practical, as the different models can't live in the same collection (a collection can just store models from one Model class).

If you are only going to have a limited amount of different appointment types, I would suggest having one Appointment model and adding a *type* attribute that defines which type of model it is. You can then use the `initialize` method to setup defaults using the underscore `_.defaults()` function like this:

```
initialize: function(){
  var defaults;

  switch(this.get("type"){
  case "USER":
    defaults = {...};
    break;
  case "STAFF":
    defaults = {...};
    break;
  case default:
    defaults = {};
  };

  _.defaults(this.attributes, defaults); // this doesn't use the set functions and doesn't trigger any change events, neither does the default implementation in the Backbone.Model constructor
}
```